# Overlapping bodies

Tags: box2d

I have two DYNAMIC bodies body1 and body2 both defined as:

```java
final BodyDef ballBodyDef = new BodyDef();
ballBodyDef.type = BodyType.DYNAMIC;

final PolygonShape ballShape = new PolygonShape();
ballShape.setAsBox(10f, 10f);

Body ballBody = world.createBody(ballBodyDef);
final Fixture ballFixt = ballBody.createFixture(ballShape, 0.2f);
ballFixt.setRestitution(0.7f);
ballFixt.setFriction(0.5f);
ballFixt.getFilterData().groupIndex = -1;
```

They don't collide.

Is there an easy method to check whether they overlap?

```
public boolean overlapping(Body body1, Body body2) {
    //Check overlapping ?
}
```

Comment: First question: do you want them to collide or not? Second question: dou you really want a rectangular shape if your object is named "ball"?

Comment: for the first question, no I don't want them to collide, hence the `groupIndex = -1`. For the second question, well indeed these so called balls are weirdly shaped but the shape shouldn't be relevant here :)